# How to fix values being null when deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML that I want to deserialize according to my own classes. It deserializes properly, but some of the values become null. It doesn't give an errors, and I'm not sure where the error lies.

I've tried changing the classes, serializing a memory model and then checking the output, but none of it worked to my liking. It needs to follow the XML that is provided.

My model:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "model", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
public class Model
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "folder")]
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "purpose")]
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "archimate", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Archimate { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

My XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archimate:model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:archimate="http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate" name="Archisurance" id="11f5304f" version="3.1.1"> 
   <folder name="Business" id="8c90fdfa" type="business">
     <folder name="Actors" id="fa63373b">
       <element xsi:type="archimate:BusinessInterface" id="1544" name="mail"/>
     </folder>
   </folder>
   <purpose>An example of a fictional Insurance company.</purpose>
</archimate:model>
```

This the result im getting after deserializing.
I cant post pictures (due to reputation) so i am just posting a link.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv1Mj.png)

I would expect the purpose field to say "An example of a fictional Insurance company", but it is null.

Comment: `[XmlElement(ElementName = "purpose", Namespace = "")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize your XML with the following data model:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "model", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
public class Model
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "folder", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "purpose", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
public class Folder
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "folder", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<Element> Element { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(BusinessInterface))]
public abstract class Element
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "BusinessInterface", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
public class BusinessInterface : Element
{
}
```

Notes:

- The root element `<archimate:model>` is in the `archimate:` namespace, but its child elements are not in any namespace, since the `archimate:` namespace is not the default namespace.  Thus it's necessary to indicate to `XmlSerializer` that these child elements are in a different namespace from their parent.  Setting [`XmlElementAttribute.Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.form?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_Form) accomplishes this.

  (It is not necessary to specify that attributes are in the default namespace, since all XML attributes are assumed to be unqualified unless otherwise specified.)
- The presence of the `xsi:type="archimate:BusinessInterface"` attribute indicates the `<element>` attribute is part of a polymorphic type hierarchy.  The `xsi:type` attribute is a [standard w3c attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#xsi_type) that allows an element to explicitly assert its type.  [`XmlSerializer` supports this attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ca1ks327(v=vs.100)) and in fact requires the presence of a subtype corresponding to the `xsi:type` and declared through the [`[XmlInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute.

  For details see *[How to: Control Serialization of Derived Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-control-serialization-of-derived-classes)*.

  Here I made an arbitrary choice of properties to include in the base class `Element` and the derived class `BusinessInterface`.  You may need to adjust this choice given a more complete XML sample.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7O4jmT).